# How does sharepoint get affected when we change the domain name

Tags: sharepoint-server, domain

We have a scenario in which we need to move a machine form one domain to other.
We have computer name c1 with domain name d1 having standalone SharePoint 2010/2013 in it.

Now I would like to change the domain name to d2 for same machine c1. Domain d1 is no more in use. How does it will affect the SharePoint? what are the steps to over come this?

Regards
Prakash

Answer (score 2):

I highly suggest you build a new SharePoint farm at d2 using the same farm topology. Then process migration from old to new farm.

There are a lot of resource about migration but none (almost) for domain change. SharePoint is so tightly bind with domain name and it is very risky to change.